# MySQL insert into values (select)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert value into mysql 5.1 table using the following statement

```
INSERT INTO `bp_measurements`
(`id_patient`, `time`, `location`, `systolic`, `diastolic`) 
VALUES (
'2',
'2015-12-26 13:19:35',
(SELECT `id` FROM `gps_locations` WHERE `lon` = 20.40930 AND `lat` = 48.94990`),
'110',
'70'
)
```

But I am getting syntax error MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`),'110','70')' at line 2 (sorry for not putting this into code but it is not working because of apostrophes used). What am I doing wrong? I have tried some other solution from stackoverflow but I cant get them working

Thanks in forward

**EDIT:**
this is the correct version of my statement

```
INSERT INTO `bp_measurements`
(`id_patient`, `time`, `location`, `systolic`, `diastolic`) 
VALUES (
'2',
'2015-12-26 13:19:35',
(SELECT `id` FROM `gps_locations` WHERE `lon` = 20.40930 AND `lat` = 48.94990),
'110',
'70'
)
```

both these and accepted answer works so feel free to use any of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `syntax`

Add the *constant values* to the `select` column list in order of insert column list

```
INSERT INTO `bp_measurements` 
            (`id_patient`, 
             `time`, 
             `location`, 
             `systolic`, 
             `diastolic`) 
SELECT '2', 
       '2015-12-26 13:19:35', 
       `id`, 
       '110', 
       '70' 
FROM   `gps_locations` 
WHERE  `lon` = 20.40930 
       AND `lat` = 48.94990
```

Comment: actualy even my solution is working I just forget to remove one apostrophe I will post correct version too

Comment: @horin - unless your sub-query returns more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

Modified Insert statement as:

```
INSERT INTO bp_measurements(id_patient, time, location, systolic, diastolic) (SELECT '2' AS id_patient,'2015-12-26 13:19:35' AS time,id AS location,'110' AS systolic,'70' AS diastolic FROM gps_locations WHERE lon = 20.40930 AND lat = 48.94990)
```